# AngularJS - compile elements added through ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Here is my problem: I create buttons dynamically with ng-repeat and their ng-click doesn't work. From what I found so far, I have to compile these buttons to make sure angular knows about the new directives but I don't know how to do that. I tried creating a new directive to do so but I must be doing something wrong since it's still not working.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="content">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">
            <span>item.text {{$index}}</span>
            <button ng-click="deleteItem({{$index}})">Delete item</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add item</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function content($scope) {
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        $scope.items.push({text: "test"});
    };

    $scope.deleteItem = function(index) {
        $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
    };
}
```

thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly off on the `ng-repeat`. Try changing to this and see if it works:

```
<button ng-click="deleteItem($index)">Delete item</button>
```

The expression that you put inside the `ng-click` never should have interpolation braces like that. Anything you put in there is already evaluated against the context of the current scope.

You haven't written any new directives (at least shown in this example), so there should be nothing you need to worry about there.